# If $x$ is càdlàg, can we show $\{t\ge0:x(t)=\Delta\}=\{t\ge0:x(t-)=\Delta\text{ or }x(t)=\Delta\}$?

Tags: general-topology, limits, probability-theory, continuity, stochastic-processes

Let $E$ be a topological space, $E^\ast=E\cup\{\Delta\}$ denote the Alexandroff one-point extension of $E$, $x:[0,\infty)\to E^\ast$ be right-continuous and $$\zeta:=\inf\underbrace{\{t\ge0:x(t)=\Delta\}}_{=:\:I}.$$

We can easily show that either $\zeta\in I$ (hence $\zeta<\infty$ and $x(\zeta)=\Delta$) or $I=\emptyset$ (hence $\zeta=\infty$ and $x(t)\in E$ for all $t\ge0$.

Assume $\Delta$ is *absorbing for $x$*, i.e. $$\forall s\ge0:(x(s)=\Delta\Rightarrow\forall t\ge s:x(t)=\Delta)\tag1$$ and hence $$x(t)=\Delta\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in[\zeta,\infty)\tag2.$$

> Assuming that $$x(t-):=\lim_{s\to t-}x(s)$$ exists for all $t\ge0$ (with the convention that $x(0-):=x(0)$), I would like to show that $$I=\tilde I:=\{t\ge0:x(t-)=\Delta\text{ or }x(t)=\Delta\}.$$

$I\subseteq\tilde I$ is trivial. Let $t\in\tilde I$. If $x(t)=\Delta$, then $t\in I$. So, assume $x(t-)=\Delta$. If $t=0$, then $x(t)=\Delta$ and hence $t\in I$. So, assume $t>0$.

How do we conclude $t\in I$? Maybe we can show that there must be a $s\in[0,t]$ with $x(s)=\Delta$ and hence we can conclude $x(t)=\Delta$ by $(1)$.

> *Remark*: If it's not possible to show this, I would like at least to show that $$\inf I=\inf\tilde I.\tag3$$

Comment: What is $x$ is constant on $[0,1)$, with some value in $E$ and on $[1,\infty)$, with value $\Delta$?

Comment: @hartkp Do you think this is a counterexample? If so, I don't see why. We've got $x(1-)\in E$ and so the remaining case considered in my proof attempt above doesn't occur for $t=1$. And if $t\ne1$, then $x(t-)=x(t)$.

Comment: I misinterpreted the definition of $\tilde I$.
However: let $E=[0,1)$ and $E^*=[0,1]$ and define $x(t)=t-[t]$. Then $I=\emptyset$ and $\tilde I=\mathbb{N}$.